# Which file to base off of when writing relative path with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, relative-path, imagebackground

I'm using bootstrap (imported styles using link so don't have a local css file), and am trying to set image as background for a div. The relative path I'm writing doesn't work. I searched online and everyone says to base the relative path off of css file (but I don't have a css file due to using bootstrap via link). How shall I write my relative path to get to 'banner.jpg'?
[image]

Comment: I would start from the root .. Not work my way back ..  Start from your **base** html directory by starting with  `/` IE `url("/from/base/dir/to/static/banner.png")`

Comment: Just use full url `https://example.com/image.webp` and problem solved.

Comment: Yes using a web link works but if my image is not hosted on a website then I have to use relative path...

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are based off the file in question. If you're not using a CSS file and instead you've got a `<style>` block in an html file, then make the path relative to that file.

If it's still not showing up, it's likely due to another issue (such as the `#banner` element not matching or having no explicit width or height).

If you add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the community can be more helpful.